# Seeking PLSS Quarter of Quarter Sections in Oregon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, united-states, plss

I'm looking for a quarter of a quarter of a section (PLSS) which is 40 acres in size for the state of Oregon. I looked at several government and Oregon state web site and could not find it. The only thing I can find is Township, Range, Section.

Earlier threat (2 years ago) refers to creating a quarter of a quarter grid using QGIS, but I'm using ArcMap 10.5 and looking for a completed shapefile, not creating one from scratch.

See image bellow (circled in red).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my own question in here:
https://www.blm.gov/services/geospatial/GISData/oregon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The REST service endpoint 'https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer' layer 3 has exactly what you're looking for: PLSS aliquot quarter-quarters.

Comment: Another question for you Rudy, do you know why some quarters are labeled as "L4", "L11" instead of "NENE" or "SWNE"? Is it because they don't fall into the traditional quarter size? (40 acres)

Comment: Yes, they're technically "Government Lots", variable in size and configuration (e.g., near water bodies). However, the layer 3 attributes also labels quarter-quarter sections on the north and west sections of a township as "NENE" etc, if they are close to a "normal" QQ aliquot partition.